# Service Variable not getting updated in a component in Angular

Tags: angular, observable

service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class EditorService {

floorplanList: FloorplanConfiguration[] = [];

floorPlansChnged = new Subject<FloorplanConfiguration[]>();
floorplans = this.floorPlansChnged.asObservable();

loadFloorplan(){
return this.floorService.getFloorPlans().pipe(
      map((fp) => {
        if (fp && fp.items) {
          this.floorplanList = floorplanConfigs.items;
          this.floorPlansChnged.next(this.floorplanList);
          return this.floorplanList;
        }
        return [];
      })
    );
}
```

component.ts

```
this.editorService.floorplans.subscribe((fp) => {
      this.floorplanList = fp;
      console.log('updated fp', this.floorplanList);
      this._createFloorplanMenu();
    });
```

Here I dont get the updated floorplanList if its value got updated in service file.

Answer (score -1):

There are few problems with your code.
First of all `of(this.floorplanList)` emits once and completes immediately, it doesn't watch over your `floorplanList`.

You can use something like `Subject` and use `next` function to send new data to the stream whenever you want to notify observers with new floor plans.

In your code, you could do something like:

```
@Injectable()
export class EditorService {

floorPlans = new Subject<FloorplanConfiguration[]>();

getFloorPlans(): Observable<FloorplanConfiguration[]> {
  return this.floorPlans.asObservable();
}

loadFloorPlans(): void {
  return this.floorService.getFloorPlans().pipe(
      map(fp => fp?.items ?? [])
    ).subscribe(this.floorPlans);
}
```

Comment: Yes I have used that also. In every case it returns the old floorplanList to the component even if it got changed in the service. Using Subject also same thing is happening.

Comment: @Gini Can you edit your question and add the version with the subject you have tried?

Comment: yes I edited it

Comment: I tried your code. Currently its not going inside subscribe in my component hence this.floorplanList is not yet getting updated.

Comment: Do you call `loadFloorPlans` from somewhere at all?

Comment: Yes I called it and if I see in debugger the the floorplans got updated and emitted too in the next. But component didn't get notified :-(

Comment: Hard to investigate further. If you want to continue, then create simple stackblitz demo to reproduce your issue.